# C# Project - Reference .pdb for native .dll

Tags: c#, dll, reference, native, pdb-files

I have a solution containing a C# Forms project that creates a UI on top of a native .dll which contains most of my program's code.

I spend most of my time working on the native code reather than C#, which means that the DLL I'm loading through my C# UI project is modified very often, and so is it's associated .pdb file which I need for debugging what I do.

However it is not possible to reference a .pdb file like one would reference a .dll, so how could I make this .pdb be copied everytime it is modified ? Adding it as an existing item is just copying it and doesn't update it when the original .pdb file gets modified.

Two only solution I see is generating the .pdb file directly into the C#'s bin/debug instead of generating it inside the native .dll project, but I'm not sure this is possible. Second solution would be to add a link to that .pdb file into the project instead of the actual .pdb file, but I'm not sure that it would work any way.

Is there a workaround to this ? I couldn't find any. Thank you.

Comment: Haven't you just tried the link solution yet? Apart from that, in the project settings, aren't there Build Events? You could copy the file there as Pre-Build Event (this is what I could do with MSVC++ 2010 I have available here).

Comment: have you considered a common output folder for your application and native dll?

Comment: @Aconcagua I have tried what you suggested, i.e add post-build events using batch scripts, and it seems to work if you can get the batch to work. I think it's cleaner because it's the project that references which takes care of taking what it needs. But since I can't get my batch scripts to work due to batch's strange way of handling quotes, and since this language is a huge piece of crap that should have never existed, I think I will just change the output directories of the .pdb in my DLL project, which does work. If you make your comment an answer with a bit more details i'll accept it.

Comment: There is more than one solution.  By far the simplest one is to do *nothing*.  The path to the PDB is recorded into the DLL, something you can see with dumpbin.exe.  So it is just fine in the directory where it was originally created by the linker.

Comment: @HansPassant Ah. But is it just the base name, the relative path or the full path that is stored in the .dll ? Because if my .dll gets moved from the DLL project's output folder to the C# projet's output folder and not the .pdb, the path has to be absolute otherwise the .dll will poiter to nothing, right ?

Answer (score 0):

MSVC provides Build-Events (MSVC++ 2010: project's properties -> 'Configuration Properties' -> 'Build Events' – this exists for C# and in later MSVC versions, too, possibly at another location, however). You can define pre- and post-build events there (in case of C++, pre-link events, too).

You can call shell commands, call a batch script, or (if you have installed an appropriate interpreter) event perl or python scripts. From within such a script (either as post build for the dll, copying the .pdb file away, or – what I would prefer personally – from within the C# project as pre build event).